# Как добавить ссылку на БД в SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Настраиваю SQL Server Data Tools VS 2016 для двух БД. Подскажите, как добавить ссылки на БД, если обе базы в некоторых разных местах вызываются друг у друга.

То есть в один проект настроил ссылку на проект, а при добавлении в другой проект ссылки пишет:

> ..Добавление этого проекта в виде ссылки может породить циклическую зависимость.

И есть ли возможность добавить ссылку на БД, без создания проекта для этой базы?

Может что-то забыл сказать, дополню вопрос. Спасибо за любую помощь :)